# The radical of a non monomial ideal in a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

What is the way one finds the radical of an ideal $I$ in a polynomial ring in $2$ or more variables $\mathbb{K} [X_1,...,X_n]$ ? I can find simple expressions for the radical of a monomial ideal. I need an example for the radical of an ideal that is non monomial in the case in which $\mathbb{K}$ is a non algebraically closed field and in the case where $\mathbb{K}$ is algebraically closed.Can you provide two such examples ? I know the definition but it does not help me.

I will highly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: This is the question I asked in my post. If I knew that, I was not going to post my question.

Comment: I will appreciate an answer of yours related to the example you gave. Thanks.